# Zip multipartfile and store via FTP

Tags: java, zip, ftp-client

I take a multipartfile (i.e. `SAMPLE.csv`) in input.
I should zip it (i.e. `SAMPLE.zip`) and store it via FTP.

```
public void zipAndStore(MultipartFile file) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
         InputStream is = file.getInputStream()) {
         ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("SAMPLE.zip");
         zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
         byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
         int length;
         while ((length = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
              zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
         }
         zos.closeEntry();
         storeFtp("SAMPLE.zip", new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
}
```

The `storeFtp` use the `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(String remote, InputStream local)` method.

The problem is that the uploaded file is corrupted and i'm unable to manually decompress.
What's wrong?

Comment: Do Base 64 encoding and then Zip it.  Please look into this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681239/base64-encode-a-file-and-compress-it

Comment: Also with Base64, the zipped file is corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A zipfile has a list of `DirEntries` and a `endLocator` at the end of the file (after all the ZipFileRecords, i.e. the ZipEntries in the code).

So you probably have to close the zipfile before calling `storeFtp()` to make sure the `DirEntries` and the `endLocator` are written to the file:

```
zos.closeEntry();
zos.close();
storeFtp("SAMPLE.zip", new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
```

(I don't know Java that well, so I can't check or test the full code)

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190212/5708620) answer.

Comment: @user2520969 Looking at the code, I also think you have to name the ZipEntry SAMPLE.csv instead of SAMPLE.zip, since it's the file inside the zipfile.